# How to allow multiple if and fix "Expected an assignment or function call" and &&

Tags: jquery, forms, function, expression, variable-assignment

Sorry for the cringy code. I'm a rookie to web dev and especially jQuery.

I'm looking to keep an "add to cart" disabled unless all required inputs are met.

I realize I can just use required="" or required/> on the form with HTML5 however, I'd like to disable the add to cart button also.

I've already tried using && and it doesn't seem to be picking up the multiples "ifs"

Here's an example form

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="fileInput" id="fileInput" /><br>
    <input type="radio" name="properties[Background]" id="keep" />
    <label for="keep">Keep</label>
    <input type="radio" name="properties[Background]" id="remove" />   
    <label for="remove">Remove</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="properties[Shape]" id="Shaped" />
    <label for="keep">Shaped</label>
    <input type="radio" name="properties[Shape]" id="Square" />   
    <label for="remove">Squarede</label><br>
    <input class="choice" id="e-mail" type="email" name="properties[E-Mail]" placeholder="E-Mail Address"><br>
    <textarea class="choice" id="description" type="description" name="properties[Description]" placeholder="Example: I only want to use the dogs face."></textarea><br>
   <input id="checkoutbtn" type="submit" value="submit" disabled />
</form>
```

And jQuery that I'm using

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $('input:file').change && $("input[name='properties[Background]']").change && $("input[name='properties[Shape]']").change && $("input[name='properties[E-Mail]']").change (
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('#checkoutbtn').prop('disabled',false); 
                } 
            }
            );
    });
```

I'm getting a bug and 1 error. The bug is, whichever of the && is listed last is the only requirement that needs to be met instead of all of them.

The error I'm getting is "expected an assignment or function call instead saw an expression"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have incorrect syntax.  If you want to assign a change handler to all 4 of your selectors, you don't join their `.change` functions with `&&` like you have done.. instead, you join their selectors together with `,`.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        $("input:file, input[name='properties[Background]'], input[name='properties[Shape]'], input[name='properties[E-Mail]']").change(
            function(){
                if ($(this).val()) {
                    $('#checkoutbtn').prop('disabled',false); 
                } 
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Update:

To require all 4 fields be provided with values in order to enable the checkout button, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {
        var inputs = [
            $("input:file"),
            $("input[name='properties[Background]']"),
            $("input[name='properties[Shape]']"),
            $("input[name='properties[E-Mail]']")
        ];

        $("input").change(
            function () {
                var enableCheckoutButton = inputs.reduce(
                    function (enabled, input) {
                        return enabled && input.val();
                    },
                    true
                );

                $('#checkoutbtn').prop('disabled', !enableCheckoutButton);
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: I tired it but now any time any of these selectors are met it enables the add to cart button. I need to be able to make it so that they all need to be met. http://jsfiddle.net/5z09wuL2/1/

Comment: So you want all 4 fields to be provided to enable the add to cart button ?

Comment: Yes I would need the button to be fully disabled unless all 4 fields are provided.

Comment: It worked! You sir, are an amazing person. Thank you for your time.